# Error not properly passing message in sveltekit

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I am having an issue where sveltekit error function found [at this link](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/errors) is not passing message correctly. See below code for example. The css classes are windicss classes.

Here is my +page.server.ts

```
import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit'
import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types'

export const load: PageServerLoad = ({ url }) => {
  throw error(404, {
    message: 'Not found',
    code: 'NOT_FOUND'
  })
}
```

Here is the +error.svelte page

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { page } from '$app/stores'
  import turtle from '$images/error/turtle-optimized.webp'
</script>

<section class="flex flex-col justify-around">
  <div class="flex flex-row justify-center">
    <h1>
      {$page.status}
      {#if $page.error}
        <!-- Debugging line below -->
        {JSON.stringify($page.error)}
        : {$page.error.message}
      {/if}
    </h1>
  </div>
  <span class="flex flex-row justify-center">
    <a href="/" class="w-50 mr-1 grid btn-blue"> Home </a>
    <a href="/shop" class="w-50 ml-1 grid btn-blue"> Shop </a>
  </span>
  <span class="grid justify-center">
    <img class="rounded-[8%]" width="400rem" src={turtle} alt="Sea turtle" />
  </span>
</section>
```

I have tried to pass the message to the error page and display using

```
JSON.stringify($page.error)
```

the value that is displayed is

```
{"message":"Error: 404"}
```

I expect the value for

```
JSON.stringify($page.error)
```

to be

```
{"message":"Not Found"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified whether or not you have a corresponding `+page.svelte` file for the `+page.server.ts`, but if you don't my guess is that SvelteKit will throw its own 404 error if you don't handle it, and that is taking precedence over your own. Additionally, I'm pretty sure that any error inside a `page.server.ts` will simply pass as either a default 404 or a vague Internal Error before being passed to the client. Perhaps take a look at the [SvelteKit Docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#shared-hooks-handleerror) for some more info on this. How you handle your error will depend on your specific situation, so more info on what you are trying to accomplish would be great.

Comment: Turns out I was changing the wrong error page haha. It was in a dynamic route page rather than the top level where I was changing it. Seems to work without a +page.svelte though.